# visual studio setup project: I can't add directories

Tags: visual-studio

I've just created the setup project. I've added the output file in the application folder and the shortcuts in the User's desktop and programs menus. Not a single problem here.

My application works with "documents" subdirectories but I haven't been able yet to create those directories during the installation process. I've included the "User's application data folder" special directory (which is something like C:\Users\UserName\Documents) and I've created a new folder in it. Both directories are configured to always create, so if the folder is empty, it should be created as well. It doesn't work well!!!

I use: visual studio 2008 in windows 7 (which is from 2009), the setup target plateform is x64 and the main software is configured on release (which is 64 bits)

the User's application data folder is set up to AlwaysCreate=True

[image: the User's application data folder is set up to AlwaysCreate=True]

the so called "aaa" subdirectory is set up to AlwaysCreate=True as well
[image: the so called "aaa" subdirectory is set up to AlwaysCreate=True as well]

Any help?

PS: I had struggled with that 15 years ago with the first versions of visual studio (2002, 2005), 5 years ago with this same 2008 version.

PS2: if I have not more than 2 links it's because I don't have at least 10 reputation.

Comment: It's unclear what your specific question is here. Are you talking about authoring an installer?

Comment: I want to create an installer which creates dynamically a new folder which will be a subfolder of the "documents" folder. For example C:\Users\eric\Documents\mynewdirectory. I'd like to do it using the installer capability

Answer (score 1):

I will answer myself as nobody does. This was a language mistake. Let's see:

```
in french: mes documents

in spanish: mis documentos

in english: documents
```

I thought I had to use in the setup application, in the File System on Target Machine: "User's application data folder" and what I had to use was "User's personal data folder".

personal data = documents

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaG9s.png)

A little criticism: Why don't we call it "mydocuments"? that "my" word is present in french and spanish, why not in english? homegeneity perhaps?

Imperfection is really hard to understand. I could have done it in a few line of codes but what would happen if I want to add an image for example? not possible to create it dynamically, right?